# How to use JavaScript in Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I want to have a JavaScript file available for a view in my Rails app.

```js
// app/javascript/custom/manage.js

document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue'
const test = document.getElementById('test')
```

```rb
# config/importmap.rb

pin_all_from "app/javascript/custom", under: "custom"
```

```rb
# app/views/locations/manage.html.erb

<%= javascript_include_tag "custom/manage", defer: true %>
```

When I navigate back to the `manage` view, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of const test
```

I suspect this is because of how Turbo works. Because I tried commenting it out in the `application.js` file and the error was gone.

Comment: @mechnicov Tried it now and it didn't work. (`Failed to register controller: hello (controllers/hello_controller` and `Uncaught DOMException: Node.removeChild: The node to be removed is not a child of this node` on refresh).   



`javascript_import_module_tag` works as it doesn't load the JavaScript on subsequent visits to the page - but that's a bug for me because I want the JS to be associated to with the view and run everytime I visit the view rendered by `manage.html.erb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you need selective import modules [feature](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails?tab=readme-ov-file#selectively-importing-modules)

It's possible to selectively import modules on specific pages, add at the top of your view using [`content_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for)

```
<%# app/views/locations/manage.html.erb %>

<% content_for :custom_js do %>
  <%= javascript_import_module_tag "custom/manage" %>
<% end %>
```

And in the layout

```
<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
<%= yield(:custom_js) %>
```

`javascript_importmap_tags` should be first

Comment: This works for the initial page load. But when I navigate away from the page, and then come back to it, the JavaScript stops working.

Comment: @Alabhya did you try to wrap you script with event handler? `document.addEventListener('turbo:load', () => { document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue'; const test = document.getElementById('test') })`

Comment: Yes. I get `Uncaught TypeError: input is null` when I navigate to a different page.

Comment: What is input? There is no any input in the question

Comment: Sorry. I added a input field and attached an event listener to it for the click event, in addition to the code in the question. 
Looks like the JavaScript file is loaded once and then used for all the views, once loaded - causing the error.